# How to convert this 1540621628 to proper date?

Tags: php, date, datetime, phalcon

I'm trying to convert `1540621628` value which is coming from Database `date_created` field. I want this to be converted to proper date.

What i tried:

```
date("m/d/Y H:i:s", strtotime($symptom[ 'date_created' ]));
```

But it's printing 12/31/1969 19:00:00 which isn't valid value because i converted the `1540621628` in https://www.epochconverter.com/ and it gives proper date i.e

> GMT: Saturday, October 27, 2018 7:06:34.154 AM Your time zone:
>   Saturday, October 27, 2018 12:06:34.154 PM GMT+05:00

Comment: @Shehzad how is it duplicate? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) on a timestamp, just pass the timestamp directly to date:

```
$symptom[ 'date_created' ] = 1540621628 ;
echo date("m/d/Y H:i:s", $symptom[ 'date_created' ]);
```

Output

```
10/27/2018 08:27:08
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a ton brother.

Comment: @Imaduddin Feel free to accept this as a valid answer if it solved your problem